# Delete multiple contacts in Windows 8 People App

Tags: windows-8, contacts, windows-8-people-app

Is it possible to select multiple contacts in the People application instead of one at the time, so I can delete them all at once?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, at least I couldn't find a way after ten to fifteen minutes of poking around the app.

The best way to manage contacts in bulk may be to go to the source of them (Google Contacts for your Gmail contacts, or Windows Live for your Hotmail contacts) and deal with them there.

Changes made at the source should sync within the People app.